# ‘invalid context 0x0’ error when using CGContext* functions

Tags: cocoa-touch, quartz-2d, cgcontext

```
/*  Adding the Path */
UserGraphBuff = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UserGraphBuff,5,10,0,1);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UserGraphBuff, 2 );

CGContextBeginPath(UserGraphBuff);  

//line to last user point
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UserGraphBuff, (*xVal)[sizeof xVal / sizeof *xVal - 1], (*yNewVal)[sizeof yNewVal / sizeof *yNewVal - 1]);
//line to rest of user points in reverse order
for (int i = sizeof xVal / sizeof *xVal - 1; i > -1; i--){
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UserGraphBuff, (*xVal)[i], (*yNewVal)[i]);
}

//EOFill
CGContextEOFillPath(UserGraphBuff);
```

Above is the code I am trying to work through. Its supposed to do what CGContext says it does but I am not getting any thing drawn. 
**I keep getting this error:**

```
Fri Oct 28 13:18:40 case.app testApplication[4127] <Error>: CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor: invalid context 0x0
Fri Oct 28 13:18:40 case.app testApplication[4127] <Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0
Fri Oct 28 13:18:40 case.app testApplication[4127] <Error>: CGContextBeginPath: invalid context 0x0
Fri Oct 28 13:18:40 case.app testApplication[4127] <Error>: CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0
Fri Oct 28 13:18:40 case.app testApplication[4127] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
```

I reference the CGContextRef in my header file.

i don't think i understand CGContext well enough nor do i know what CGContextRef should be.

Comment: Where does this code live? In the `drawRect` of a `UIView` subclass?

Comment: What the heck is that? What does it do? Is it called by `-drawRect:`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For your code to work, it needs to be executed in the `drawRect` method of your `UIView` subclass (and you don't call `drawRect` directly - this is called by the OS when it needs the UIView to render itself). You're presumably trying to run this code from a touch event or from `viewDidLoad` or something like that.

Comment: Its in its own method of several things. its not called alone. I am running this from a check event. I want the users data to be cross referenced with the actual drawing (its practically a tracing game). At this point I am just trying to do a path of what the person as drawn all ready.

Comment: To reiterate: your code will not work (meaning it will throw the errors your seeing) unless it's running in the `drawRect` method of a `UIView` subclass.

Comment: And to explain: UIView sets up the current context before calling your `drawRect:`. This is a feature: You draw when drawing is need, which the system keeps track of for you. Don't fight it; move your drawing code where it's supposed to be, and work with the system. When something changes that the view will need to redraw for, set the view as needing display.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato: No, he is not incorrect. You are looking at the Quartz docs, which are lower level than UIKit. You use Quartz to draw, when UIKit tells you to. The documentation that covers `drawRect:`, needing display, etc. is the [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/).

Comment: @JohnRiselvato Sorry, but MusiGenesis is exactly right. This is the correct answer.

Comment: I understand my confusion looking back, the source I saw back then looked like it was doing all the CGContext in it's own function not drawRect:, the drawRect: of that source actually called the function, which allowed the drawing to occur. I've learned a lot over the last two years fortunately.