# Why doesn't CoreGraphics FillPath fill the specified path

Tags: core-graphics, xamarin.ios

I've got some Xamarin.iOS CoreGraphics code that draws red triangles at the ends of several white lines of various angles.

[image]

I want have the red triangles filled in instead of being rendered as outlines but when I use the graphic context command FillPath() instead of StrokePath() the red triangles don't appear.

[image]

Here's the DrawArrowHead code (called by the line drawing code after each individual line is drawn).

```
private void DrawArrowHead(PointF[] line, int size)
{
    // Create the arrowhead and the lines from individual arrowhead points
    PointF[] arrowhead = new PointF[] {
        new PointF(0.0f - size, 0.0f),
        new PointF(0.0f, 0.0f - size),
        new PointF(0.0f + size, 0.0f)
    };

    PointF[] line1 = new PointF[] {new PointF(arrowhead[0].X, arrowhead[0].Y), new PointF(arrowhead[1].X, arrowhead[1].Y)};
    PointF[] line2 = new PointF[] {new PointF(arrowhead[1].X, arrowhead[1].Y), new PointF(arrowhead[2].X, arrowhead[2].Y)};
    PointF[] line3 = new PointF[] {new PointF(arrowhead[2].X, arrowhead[2].Y), new PointF(arrowhead[0].X, arrowhead[0].Y)};

    // Begin drawing the arrowhead
    gctx.SaveState();

    UIColor.Red.SetStroke();
    gctx.SetFillColor(UIColor.Red.CGColor);

    gctx.BeginPath();

    double angleInRadians = Math.Atan2 (line[0].Y - line[1].Y, line[0].X -line[1].X);

    gctx.TranslateCTM(line[1].X, line[1].Y);
    gctx.RotateCTM((float)(angleInRadians -  Math.PI / 2));

    path.AddLines(line1);
    path.AddLines(line2);
    path.AddLines(line3);

    path.CloseSubpath();

    gctx.AddPath(path);

    gctx.StrokePath();

    gctx.RestoreState();
}
```

When I replace gctx.StrokePath() with gctx.FillPath() I get the white lines but no arrowheads.

[image]

When I replace gctx.StrokePath() with gctx.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke) I get the red triangles but they're not filled in.

[image]

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

```
Update - 03.22.13
```

Turns out @poupou's answer was correct but, compounded by some of my other coding "misinterpretations," didn't solve my problem right away. However, since it pointed me in the right direction towards a solution I'm accepting his answer.

I first learned how to use CoreGraphics via Mike Bluestein's excellent [Drawing with CoreGraphics in MonoTouch](http://mikebluestein.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/drawing-with-coregraphics-in-monotouch-2/) post. However, a little knowledge is a dangerous thing and when I began applying these concepts to my own work, I inadvertently mixed graphics context and path methods when I shouldn't have.

After a lot of googling, reading, and reviewing other peoples CoreGraphics source code (props to Nina Vyedin and Bryan Costanich of Xamarin for their Drawing [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/Drawing)), I came up with a DrawArrowhead method that works.

```
private void DrawArrowHead(PointF[] line, int size)
{
    gctx.SaveState();
    UIColor.Red.SetStroke();
    UIColor.Red.SetFill();
    double angleInRadians = Math.Atan2 (line[0].Y - line[1].Y, line[0].X -line[1].X);

    gctx.BeginPath();
    gctx.TranslateCTM(line[1].X, line[1].Y);
    gctx.RotateCTM((float)(angleInRadians -  Math.PI / 2));

    PointF[] arrowhead = new PointF[] {
        new PointF (0.0f - arrowHeadSize, 0.0f),
        new PointF (0.0f, 0.0f - arrowHeadSize),
        new PointF (0.0f + arrowHeadSize, 0.0f)
    };

    gctx.MoveTo(arrowhead[0].X, arrowhead[0].Y);
    gctx.AddLineToPoint(arrowhead[1].X, arrowhead[1].Y);
    gctx.AddLineToPoint(arrowhead[2].X, arrowhead[2].Y);

    gctx.ClosePath();                   
    gctx.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);                                   
    gctx.RestoreState();
}
```

Here's the final result.

[image]

Note: I had to move the DrawArrowHead code out of it's method and into my UIView's Draw method to avoid Invalid Context errors when drawing the second, third, fourth, and fifth line/arrowhead combinations (you can read about that type of error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932654/invalid-context-0x0-error-when-using-cgcontext-functions)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `path.CloseSubpath();` on a `CGPath` is not identical to calling `gctx.ClosePath();` on a `CGContext` (where the stroke/fill will be done). Did you try the later ?

Comment: Replacing path.CloseSubpath() with gctx.ClosePath() gives the same results when using gctx.FillPath() and gctx.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke). But it was a good suggestion.

Comment: path.CloseSubpath is used on reusable paths, gctx.ClosePath on paths that are flushed from the graphics context when painted.

Comment: Using gctx.ClosePath was a step in the right direction. See the Update - 03.22.13 section in my original question.

Comment: @billmaya Glad you got it working! I did not *yet* had time to try it myself.