# Why this taking screenshot code fails?

Tags: ios, uilabel, xcode4.5

```
- (UIImage*) screenshot
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.opaque, 0.0);
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    PO (NSStringFromCGRect(self.bounds));
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return myImage;
}
```

It works on all of my UIView. However, if I generate my own UIView in code like this

```
+(UIImage *) imageAsScreenShotFromLabel:(NSString*) strLabel
{
    UILabel * lbl=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    lbl.text =strLabel;
    [lbl resizeToStretch];
    return lbl.screenshot;
}
```

It fails and I got this error:

```
Sep 12 15:41:05 Jupiter.local [70630] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Sep 12 15:41:05 Jupiter.local [70630] <Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0
Sep 12 15:41:05 Jupiter.local [70630] <Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
Sep 12 15:41:05 Jupiter.local [70630] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

Why?

Comment: You can use PO in code??

Comment: What is `self.bounds.size` in this case?

Comment: @borrrden should be (0,0) since the label is never given a frame

Comment: If that is the case then that is why this fails

Comment: check your context, log shows your context is nil, this is what i am getting..

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932654/invalid-context-0x0-error-when-using-cgcontext-functions

Answer (score -1):

As per the [documenation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

*The current graphics context is nil by default. Prior to calling its drawRect: method, view objects push a valid context onto the stack, making it current.*

So you need to put this code in the drawRect method

Comment: Notice he is creating his own context via `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`